# Avoid a library from going to final image in Yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am working on building an Yocto image in which I use some Open Source libraries whiich are required only during the build time. Currently they are not part of the final image. Is there a way to make sure that they do not make it to the final image in the future also?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I posted an answer, but please provide more info: is the lib recipe separate from the main recipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `PACKAGE_EXCLUDE` to be more helpful which throws an error when the packages of the OSS libraries are being installed on the image by anyone.

Refer the doc - https://docs.yoctoproject.org/2.5.1/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-PACKAGE_EXCLUDE

Answer (score 0):

If any recipe is found in the final image that means the recipe is specified into one of the install variables (`IMAGE_INSTALL`, `IMAGE_FEATURES`, ...) or it is specified as a run time dependency of another recipe (`RDEPENDS`).

It could be one of these cases:

1. If the libraries are provided by a separate recipe and that recipe is specified as `DEPENDS` of your main recipe. Make sure that the recipe of the libraries is not present in `IMAGE_INSTALL` or any image installation variable. And make sure that it is not present in any `RDEPENDS` variable.
2. If the main recipe is generating libraries and using them to compile the final result, it is easy, just make sure that they are not installed or mentioned in `do_install` task.

Comment: Is it relevant also for build time (and potentially) run-time packages like the `gcc` package? Meaning, in the final image I'm building there are some folders with gcc related header files that are not needed in the final image, for example: `usr/lib64/gcc/9.2.0/` and `/usr/lib/gcc//9.2.0/` and the actual executable `/usr/bin/gcc`